# Android: Error in sending List<string> to WCF web service

Tags: android, wcf

I'm trying to send `List<string>` from Android to a WCF web service (built using C#). I'm getting the error message below:

This is the WCF web service Error Message:

> Operation 'insertRecord' in contract 'IService1' has a query variable named 'list' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]', but type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' is not convertible by 'QueryStringConverter'.  Variables for UriTemplate query values must have types that can be converted by 'QueryStringConverter'.

This is Android code for `List<string>`:

```
final List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("Item 1");
list.add("Item 2");
list.add("Item 3");
list.add("Item 4");
list.add("Item 5");

HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:3113/Service1.svc/insertRecord?list="+list);
```

This is the WCF web service code:

```
public string insertRecord(List<string> list)
{
    DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();
    return dataAccess.insertRecord(list);
}

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "insertRecord?list={list}")]
string insertRecord(List<string> list);
```

Can anyone please guide me in this?

Comment: You're welcome. Note that on SO you can edit your own questions to improve them as well, which is usually appreciated (and -if substantial- will bump your question).

Comment: By the way, I'm no expert on Java, but have you tried checking the actual URL you're constructing? What does the `+list` bit at the end of the URL generate?

Comment: its object list wanna send to WCF web service..